# Is there a way to completey uninstall and then reinstall ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, xcode, ggplot2, rcpp

I am very new to R and coding in general, so just a heads up.

I installed R on my terminal and now I installed ggplot2. The installation was successful, but a couple of days later I tried to open ggplot2 using "library("ggplot2")", but it says: 
"Error in library("ggplot2") : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’".

So I tried reinstalling ggplot2 using "install.packages("ggplot2"), but I am getting this error: 
RcppExports.cpp:4:10: fatal error: Rcpp.h: No such file or directory
 #include

I even tried uninstalling ggplot2 using remove.packages, but it says that there is no package called ggplot2.

Any idea what I can do to get ggplot2 successfully?

Thanks for your help!

[image: edit: added a picture of the process]

Comment: What exactly do you see when running `install.packages("ggplot2")`. Are you sure that message isn't coming from a dependency? Did R ask you if you wanted to install from source?

Comment: I also completely uninstalled/installed r-base-core and installed ggplot2, but I am getting the same problem

Comment: Maybe you should start with reading the FAQ on R for Mac, because you're on a Macbook Pro but using the installation procedure for an obscure Linux distro. Randomly installing and uninstalling components won't work. First install R correctly. Then use `install.packages("ggplot2")` from within R to download and install the Mac binaries with all dependencies.

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html

Answer (score 4):

Briefly:

1. You are not describing your situation very well. What OS? What version? What commands?
2. From the *photo* (!!) posted we learn that the terminal is on macbook, but the actual commands you list *appear* to be from Debian/Ubuntu virtual machine. Is that so?
3. If you are in fact on such an OS, just do `sudo apt-get install r-cran-ggplot2` and a *pre-made* binary will be installed for you, along with all its depdendencies including Rcpp which really is just a bystander here in your issue.